# How to see personal stats on SU.

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I would like to see my personal stats on SU. I mean by that, how many entried I've edited, on how many questions I've upvote. This is to compare on how many votes, editions or anything I miss to get a new badge by example...

Is there a way to do that?

I saw this: [OData Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) but I only see an xml file.

Hope my question was clear enough!

Comment: What browser are you using?  That link worked fine for me in chrome.  It's basically a query engine for the data with a lot of pre-made queries.  Try this one : http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries

Comment: I tried with Opera and IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the basic stats are already on your [user profile page](https://superuser.com/users/26960/r0ca). If you want some more stats - and if you have some knowledge of SQL - then you can use the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries) find out.

There are some [pretty good queries](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries?order_by=featured) that have been composed by users. Else you can probably post a new question asking for what is it that you want, and we could probably write the relevant query and help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now for me with IE. What I'd like to have is a query for each user telling how many "of these (votes, editions)" is missing before getting "that badge"...

Comment: @r0ca - just bare in mind the data explorer isn't *live* data - they only update it monthly (I think - someone confirm!).

Comment: @DMA5 it's not updated monthly - as of now now it gets updated whenever a data dump is available.

Comment: Fair enough, any idea how often that happens?

Comment: @DMA Every couple months, Jeff publishes a post on StackOverflow blog whenever a data dump is available - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/ **ed:** seems it is monthly updates..

Comment: @r0ca have a look at the popular or featured queries, chances are that those queries might have been written